# Node JS googleapis vs Rclone authentication

Tags: node.js, jwt, google-drive-api, google-apis-explorer, rclone

So, I have this peculiar question. I have a service account with given credentials. I use them both to authenticate myself to Gdrive in the Nodejs app and with rclone.
So with Rclone I am able to access the root folder and upload files/ create directories.
Using the same credentials, from Nodejs app, using official googleapis npm package and same folder ID, I am unable to list the contents of the root folder.
I have tried double checking the credentials and folder Id etc...

My question is, how is it possible that same credentials don't have access to the same folder, given that I have the default scope of /drive and /drive.appdata which should cover everything.

Any ideas on what to try next?

I tried:

1. Checking ID and credentials
2. Writing bare minimum search query which only lists the folders contents:
   `const response = await this.drive.files.list({ q:` '${parentFolderId}' in parents and mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.folder'`, fields: 'files(id)', });`
3. Using JWT as authentication method with same credentials and scopes as in Rclone config

Comment: The solution was adding flag when using google API's, on each request: supportsAllDrives: true